# Top 2 Merchants for each Account in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Thanks for checking my thread and hope you are doing well.

You are looking at some customer spending data.
An account can spend money at different merchants.
Num of merchants they spent at may vary (from 1-3 in the example below).

```
acct_id  | merchant   | total_value |
---------|------------|-------------|
23409    |  amazon    |   50000     |
23409    |  google    |   45000     |
23409    |  fbook     |   7000      |
25391    |  tiktok    |   20000     |
25391    |  amazon    |   3000      |
66366    |  amazon    |   5500      |
87025    |  google    |   5000      |
87025    |  aliexp    |   3000      |
87025    |  tiktok    |   500       |
```

I'm looking to get the result which shows top 2 merchants (based on total_value) of each account.

Roughly, the result is like:

```
acct_id  |     top_merchant     |
---------|----------------------|
23409    |  amazon,google       |
25391    |  tiktok, amazon      | 
66366    |  amazon              |
87025    |  google,aliexp       |
```

Apologies if this is such a rookie question as I am new to SQL or coding in general.

Any guidance will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Enumerate rows in CTE, select needed amount and use GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: Or seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `group by`

```
select acct_id, 
substring_index(
    group_concat(
        merchant order by total_value desc
    ), ',', 2
) 
as top_merchant from my_table group by acct_id
```

my_table has to be replaced with your table

Answer (score 0):

this query provide top tow performer of each account type

```
;With Temp As (
Select  Row_Number() Over(partition By acct_id Order BY acct_id,total_value Desc) As RowNo,
        acct_id     ,
        merchant    ,
        total_value 
From #TempData
)
Select *
From Temp
Where RowNo <= 2
```